# Insert comma separated string into multiple columns

Tags: php

I am looking for a solution where I can insert a comma separated string but split them out and insert into different columns of the same table.

I understand this can be achieved as I have looked all over the web and seen other have potentially successfully done this.

I have a simple `<textarea name="stenData" placeholder="Paste Sten Data..."></textarea>`

The data that will be inserted will ALWAYS be the same as it is copied form another source and will ALWAYS remain in the same format. like so:

RP1=8, RP2=3, RP3=1 and so on...

This will be inserted into a members table with the samn columns so `rp1`, `rp2`

At the moment I am literally just inserting the data but I understand you can wrap an `explode()` function around the posted data? I am looking for some advice really more than anything...

**UPDATE**

I am exploding on the POST input by:

```
$stenData = explode(',',  $_POST['stenData']);
```

Which gives me (as an example):

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "RP1=8" [1]=> string(5) "RP2=7" }
```

but im not sure on how to insert that into multiple columns

** UPDATE 2 **

I am trying to insert the data into my table so I am posting the data from my form like so:

```
// Dashboard Name
$dashboardName = $_POST['dashboardName'];

// Member Details
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$score_1 = $_POST['score_1'];
$score_2 = $_POST['score_2'];
$score_3 = $_POST['score_3'];
$score_4 = $_POST['score_4'];
$score_5 = $_POST['score_5'];
$score_6 = $_POST['score_6'];
$score_7 = $_POST['score_7'];
$score_8 = $_POST['score_8'];
$stenData = explode('=',  $_POST['stenData']); // this is the problem line

// Team name
$teamName = $_POST['teamName'];
```

I then try to insert, all of which are ok apart from the stenData one:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO members (firstName, lastName, score_1, score_2, score_3, score_4, score_5, score_6, score_7, score_8, dashboard_id, rp_1) 
         VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$score_1', '$score_2', '$score_3', '$score_4', '$score_5', '$score_6', '$score_7', '$score_8', '$dashboard_id', '$stenData')";
```

The error message is: `Notice: Array to string conversion` and it simply inputs the word 'array' into the column row cell.

Comment: So you want to process the data pasted into the `<textarea>`?  Where is your PHP that actually does this processing?  This should be a pretty simple use of `explode()`  - explode on the comma, then you'll have an array with elements like RP1=8.  Then split each element on the `=` and you'll have your column name and your value

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Thats exactly it, so what I have tried it `$stenData = explode(',',  $_POST['stenData']);` which output an array but im not sure how I could INSERT those array values into multiple columns - Im not sure what you mean by split the element?

Comment: Use the same `explode()` function on each element, but instead of using the comma, use the `=` sign.  This will give you an array with the column name (`rp1`) and the value (`8`).  Then you can insert the value into the appropriate column

Comment: Would you like to show your php code ? so we can help it out

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Ok so that gets me closer to where I need to be, so if I wanted to insert those values into the table columns how would I do that?

Comment: Not trying to be obnoxious, but do you know how to insert data into a database?  Loop over your data and use PDO or MySQLi to generate and execute your insert statements.

Comment: Show your code if you want specific help

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I think the OP is struggling to know how to insert the Array output in to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['stenData'] = "RP1=8,RP2=3,RP3=1";
preg_match_all("|RP([0-9]+)=([0-9]+)|", $_POST['stenData'], $matches);
$tmpArr = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value)
{
    $tmpArr['RP'.$value] = $matches[2][$key];
}
```

Result:

```
array (size=3)
  'RP1' => string '8' (length=1)
  'RP2' => string '3' (length=1)
  'RP3' => string '1' (length=1)
```